# Question on Pattern Matching: Why can I not use the same arguments for a conjuction?

Tags: haskell

### Context from Programming with haskell Textbook Page 32

> This version also has the benefit that, under lazy evaluation as
> discussed in chapter 12, if the first argument is False, then the
> result False is returned without the need to evaluate the second
> argument. In practice, the prelude defines ∧ using equations that have
> this same property, but make the choice about which equation applies
> using the value of the first argument only:
>
> ```
> True ∧ b = b
>
> False ∧ _ = False
> ```
>
> That is, if the first argument is True, then the result is the value
> of the second argument, and, if the first argument is False, then the
> result is False. Note that for technical reasons the same name may not
> be used for more than one argument in a single equation. For example,
> the following definition for the operator ∧ is based upon the
> observation that, if the two arguments are equal, then the result is
> the same value, otherwise the result is False, but is invalid because
> of the above naming requirement:

### Question

I do not understand the explanation for not being able to use the expression

```
b ∧ b = b

 __∧_ _= False
```

Comment: Pattern matching won't evaluate either argument far enough to determine if they are, indeed, equal. You have to write something like `a ∧ b | a && b = a` to force the evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To accept a definition such as

```
myFunction x x = ...
myFunction _ _ = ...
```

we need to be able to test two values for equality. That is, given two arbitrary values `x` and `y`, we need to be able to compute whether `x == y` holds.

This can be done in many cases, but (perhaps surprisingly) not all. We surely can do that when `x` and `y` are `Bool`s or `Int`s, but not when they are `Integer -> Bool` or `IO ()`, for instance, since we can not really test functions on infinitely many points, or IO actions on infinitely many worlds.

Consequently, pattern matching is allowed only when variables are used *linearly*, i.e. when the appear at most once in patterns. So, `myFunction x x = ...` is disallowed.

If needed, when `==` is defined (like on `Bool`s) we can use guards to express the same idea:

```
myFunction x1 x2 | x1 == x2  = ....
                 | otherwise = ....
```

In principle, Haskell could automatically translate non-linear patterns into patterns with guards using `==`, possible causing an error if `==` is not available for the type at hand. However, it was not defined in this way, and requires the guard to be explicitly written, if required.

This automatic translation could be convenient but could also be a source of subtle bugs, if one inadvertently reuses a variable in a pattern without realizing it.

Comment: Ok , so in the case of Booleans, for example, you could use two arguments True and True in a conjucnction to equal True, as they are fixed values and take a finite, i.e one, set of points.That they are equal by definition? Am i on the right traack with the idea?

Comment: @MathematicalMonk Yes, in a pattern you can always use constructors, so you can check whether your input boolean is `True` (or if they are both `True`, for a binary function like conjunction). So `conj True True = True ; conj b1 b2 = False` is correct. (The last unused variables are usually written as `_`, as in `... ; conj _ _ = False` to stress that they are unused)

Comment: I think there's a good reason Haskell doesn't do that translation automatically. Users would expect it to also apply in cases like `let x = 1 in case y of (0, x) -> ...`, doing an implicit equality check. That's fine when you meant to do it, but shadowing another variable is very easy to do accidentally, and this prospective language feature would give it surprising semantics.

Comment: @amalloy: For that to work, we’d need to disambiguate the two kinds of variable pattern: introduce a new variable, or compare against an existing one. We might write the former as `f ~x = …` (as with the `Strict` extension) and the latter as `f x = …`, desugaring to `f ~x' | x' == x` or `f x'@_ | x' == x = …`. But since binding a new name is far more common, it makes sense to give it the terser syntax. In GHC, we can use `ViewPatterns` to write `f ((== x) -> True) = …` or use `PatternSynonyms` to give it a name with `pattern Eq x <- x@((== x) -> True) where Eq x = x`, then write `f (Eq x) = …`

Comment: @amalloy I remember that, at some point, I used a language which did exactly that (Erlang, IIRC). I did not enjoy it.

Comment: @JonPurdy IIRC, Swift does the opposite, using `let x` for bindings, and `x` for equality test. In Haskell that would be rather inconvenient, for the reason you mention.